# How do I plot a 3D scatter graph from a 3D array ? where each markers size is given by the value in said array

Tags: python, arrays, matplotlib, matplotlib-3d

I've got myself some code that generating a 3D array but when I try to plot it i run into this error. Using the Sypder IDE

Code:

```
import numpy as np 
import math as m
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

a = 3
b = 4
c = 2

d = 0

if a > b and a > c:
    d = a
if b > a and b > c:
    d = b
if c > a and c > b:
    d = c

array = np.random.randint(0,10,(a,b,c)) # random numpy array of shape (4,5)
print(array)

x = np.linspace(0, d, d+1, dtype=int)
y = np.linspace(0, d, d+1, dtype=int)
z = np.linspace(0, d, d+1, dtype=int)

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(projection='3d')

ax.scatter(x, y, z, s = array[x,y,z])
plt.show()
```

The graph I want to generate would have a marker at every integer co-ordinate and the size of the marker would be given by the number in the array. The code works if I remove the marker size but doesn't generate the graph I want, and it doesn't work with marker size included.

I've also tried using, x,y,z =array instead of linspace but this creates a different problem.

Answer (score 0):

The first problem is that the `s` parameter expects an array of shape which is the same as `x` (or `y` or `z`)

The second problem is that in your question you said "size is given by the value in said array" - but your 3D array doesn't have any values at the grid points - you just created a grid. So you need to create an additional array with the sizes